# First examples in triangulations

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology

I am starting to study about triangulations in my algebraic topology course. We have seen the triangulation of the sphere, the closed disc and so on. Intuitively it's ok, however I couldn't find any rigorous proof of these examples.

> Anyone knows any book, site or resource to find them? 
>   Thank you very much.

Comment: I suggest you to read Hatcher's book or Munkre's book.

Comment: That second one would be *Munkres'* book.

Comment: I've already search in these books and I didn't find any rigorous prove of triangulations

Comment: What do you mean by 'proof of triangulations'? Specifically which proposition would it be about?

Comment: @Berci For example we know that the closed disk can be triangulated, i.e., we can find a homeomorphism between the closed disk and a polyhedron which is a simplicial complex with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R^n$. I couldn't find any resource with the details of this prove.